# Can't Set Environment Variables in ~/.profile

Tags: environment-variables, qt, .profile

All, I need to set environment variables in my `~/.profile` since I am running a program (QtCreator) that doesn't start a bash shell.

I cannot for the life of me get it to work though.  QtCreator will not show any of the environment variables I defined under "System Environment."

How can I do this?

---

**Edit:** Okay, actually it turns out my question is why can't I `source my_environment` where

my_environment:

```
 export SOME_PATH=blalalal
```

If I add `export SOME_PATH=blalalal` to my `~/.profile` it works.  But I can't use `source ~/.profile`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the story:

> ~/.profile - In this file you can also place environment variable assignments, since it gets executed automatically by the DisplayManager during the start-up process desktop session as well as by the login shell when one logs-in from the textual console.

([source](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#Session-wide_environment_variables))

1. solution: export the variables defined in `.profile`.

   export VAR1=foo
2. solution: put the variables in .bashrc, open a terminal and start QtCreator from command line. It should have the variables. Don't forget to export them:

   ```
   export VAR1=foo
   ```
3. solution: create a wrapper for starting your program, a small script that you run instead of running the program directly:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash

   export VAR1=foo
   program
   ```

   or

   ```
    #!/bin/bash

    VAR1=foo program
   ```
4. solution: edit the `.desktop` file used to launch the application by modifying the execute line to

   ```
    VAR1=foo program
   ```

   instead of

   ```
    program
   ```

   (haven't tested that, but it should work)
5. solution: change the environment. You are right in your comment that programs do get an environment, even if they do not read it from the `.profile`. The system-wide environment is in `/etc/environment`, but you can also set it per session, in a file in your home directory called `.pam_environment`. See [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#Session-wide_environment_variables) for more information. By the way, this page neatly explains what all the different files do and when to use which.

   However, I prefer solutions 1-3, because they change the environment of the *program* only, and not of the whole session.

Comment: Hi January, many of these solutions make sense, but I'm a hard head.  Qt Creator sees many System Variables, surely they weren't set in any of the launcher and it's extracting them from an existing source.  I thought that source is either `/etc/environment` or `/etc/profile`

Comment: You are right; see the update in solution 4.

Comment: January, the doing `export BLA=blalalbabl` in my ~/.profile worked.  However, being the hardhead, I want to source an environment file I've made from the ~/.profile... is it simply `. $HOME/my_environment.bash`

Comment: Yes, exactly, this is it (dot or `source`).

Comment: You don't need to edit your answer to say you're wrong, just edit the answer to be correct!

Answer (score 0):

Just logout and login back into the system that the `.pam-environment` file is read and the environment variable is recognized.